# Make a contrast using "not"

Tags: grammar, comparatives, computing, no-not

I want to make a contrast in the following question.

> Transfer the storage manager to the domain layer as far as interaction
>   with the local storage - is its responsibility, not the view-layer.

I feel that something is missing at the end of the sentence, this part - `not the view-layer.` In other cases of making contrast between two objects I add `one` at the end. But in this case I am not sure if I have to use it or maybe some other grammar structure.

I would be grateful for any help to make this sentence sound correctly.

P.S. If have made any other mistakes please let me know as well.

Comment: As it stands, the part before "-" is an instruction limiting the transfer 'distance' to "interaction with the local storage". The last part "not the view-layer" would be fine in an appropriate context, but the phrase "is its responsibility" seems unrelated to anything. What is the quote trying to say?

Comment: You probably want to make view-layer possessive: "not the view-layer's".  The portion at the end is about whose responsibility it is.

Comment: @fixer1234 exactly what I missed, could you please post an answer for the question ?

Comment: You need a *this* after the dash to make clear what the subject of that clause is: *—this is its responsibility, not the view-layer's*.  This will address the problem pointed out by @Lawrence. Also, note that you need an em-dash, not a hyphen, to separate the clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase at the end talks about whose responsibility it is.  Make view-layer possessive: "...is its responsibility, not the view-layer's".